# How to select from table A one row and table B multi rows?

Tags: sql, select, relational-database

I have two tables.

Pages

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| ID        | title    |    URL     |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1         | test     | test.html  |
| 2         | test2    | test2.html |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Files

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| ID        | page_id  |    name    |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 10        |    1     |   a.jpg    |
| 11        |    1     |   b.jpg    |
| 12        |    2     |   c.jpg    |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

How to select from PAGES one row and  FILES multi rows??

My query as:

```
select * from pages,files WHERE (pages.id = page_id) AND  (url='$url')
```

The output for above query:

```
test
a.jpg
```

**The output I need:**

```
test
a.jpg
b.jpg
```

Comment: (a) Do you have an FK Constraint on Files, referencing Pages ? (b) That code should work, whatever "sql" variant you are using, it is broken (c) `SELECT *`` will produce six columns, not one.  Please provide.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a sql question than anything to do with specifically PHP.
I think this is what you want, but I'm not sure with your wording.

```
SELECT pages.title, files.name 
FROM pages 
INNER JOIN files ON pages.id = files.page_id
WHERE (pages.url='$url')
GROUP BY files.name;
```

Comment: What output are you getting, you can try to GROUP BY files.name. (edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT 
    Files.Name 
FROM Files 
INNER JOIN Pages ON Files.page_id = Pages.Id
WHERE Pages.url = '$url'

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    Pages.title
FROM Pages 
WHERE Pages.url = '$url'
```