# How to select only one row from B table?

Tags: php, database, select

I have 2 tables:

sma_db

```
+----+----------+-------+
| ID |  title   | catid |
+----+----------+-------+
| 1  | Hi       |   4   |
| 2  | Hello    |   4   |
| 3  | Test     |   5   |
+----+----------+-------+
```

sma_files

```
+----+----------+---------+
| ID |  name    |entry_id |
+----+----------+---------+
| 1  | a.jpg    |    1    |
| 2  | b.jpg    |    1    |
| 3  | c.jpg    |    2    |
+----+----------+---------+
```

My query as:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sma_db 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN sma_files 
                    ON sma_db.id = sma_files.entry_id 
                    WHERE catid = '4'") or die(mysql_error());;

while($affcom = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
     $title = $affcom['title'];
     $name = $affcom['name'];
     echo $title; 
     echo $name; 
}
```

How to select only one row from **sma_files** table ???

The output for above query:

```
Hi    a.jpg
Hi    b.jpg
Hello c.jpg
```

**The output I need:**

```
Hi    a.jpg
Hello c.jpg
```

Comment: use limit 1 it will give you one result

Comment: I don't need one result, I need all results without repeating it for 2nd table

Comment: you asked this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/29905891/ what is different about this question?

Comment: Please respond to my comment above ^ - it seems kind of clear that you went around it using different table names and columns. Otherwise, I will close it as an exact duplicate.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Previous question the output one result. **I need all results without repeating it for 2nd table**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sma_db 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN sma_files 
                    ON sma_db.id = sma_files.entry_id 
                    WHERE catid = '4' 
                    GROUP BY sma_files.entry_id") 
                    or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: LIMIT 0,1 not helpful, I need all results without repeating it for 2nd table **question updated please read it carefully.**

Comment: @SaeedAknan  *"Perfect, still one problem: If I submit one record for first table without uploading image (xx.jpg) for 2nd table it will not appear in the output"*-  far as I'm concerned, you should be accepting this answer. What you're asking is totally unrelated and should be posted as a new question. There is no code in your original question to support your "new" request.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group By`

```
SELECT * FROM sma_db 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sma_files 
ON sma_db.id = sma_files.entry_id 
WHERE catid = '4'
GROUP BY `entry_id`
```

Comment: LIMIT 1 not helpful, question updated please read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

try below query

```
SELECT * FROM `sma_db` 
INNER JOIN `sma_files` 
ON `sma_db`.`id` = `sma_files`.`entry_id` 
WHERE `sma_db`.`catid` = '4'"
```